# Boundary conditions for vibrating beam

Tags: partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, boundary-value-problem

I'm solving the equation for the transverse vibrations of a Euler-Bernoulli beam fixed at both ends and subject to axial loading ([as per this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usgwu.png)). It's a similar problem to that described by Rao on page 355 of his excellent book "Vibration of Continuous Systems" ([Google books link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kWja9NTH0bEC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)), except the example he uses is for a simply supported beam.

The general solution takes the form of $y(x) = C_1\cosh(\alpha x) + C_2\sinh(\alpha x) + C_3\cos(\beta x) + C_4\sin(\beta x)$, where $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ & $C_4$ are the constants I need to find. The BCs are standard:

- $y(0)=y(L) = 0$ (zero displacement at ends)
- $y'(0)=y'(L) = 0$ (zero gradient at ends)

When I substitute these in the $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ conditions give $C_1 + C_3 = 0$ and $\alpha C_2 + \beta C_4 = 0$, respectively, while the $y(L)$ and $y'(L)$ conditions give:

1) $C_1\cosh(\alpha L) + C_2\sinh(\alpha L) + C_3\cos(\beta L) + C_4\sin(\beta L) = 0$

2) $\alpha C_1\sinh(\alpha L) + \alpha C_2\cosh(\alpha L) – \beta C_3\sin(\beta L) + \beta C_4\cos(\beta L) = 0$

Clearly the first 2 conditions can be used to reduce these last two equations into functions of $C_1$ and $C_2$ only:

3) $C_1[\cosh(\alpha L) - \cos(\beta L)] + C_2\left[\sinh(\alpha L) - \frac{\alpha}{ \beta}\sin(\beta L)\right] = 0$

4) $C_1[\alpha C_1\sinh(\alpha L) + \beta \sin(\beta L)] + C_2[\beta \cosh(\alpha L) - \alpha \cos(\beta L)] = 0$

We can now solve for $C_1$ (or $C_2$) and use this to write all the terms of the original governing equation in terms of it alone. However, there are two possible expressions for $C_1$ (and $C_2$), depending on which equation is used. 3) gives:

$C_2 = -C_1\frac{[\cosh(\alpha L) - \cos(\beta L)]}{[\sinh(\alpha L) - (\alpha /\beta )\sin(\beta L)]}$

whereas 4) gives:

$C_2 = -C_1\frac{[\alpha C_1\sinh(\alpha L) + \beta \sin(\beta L)]}{[\beta \cosh(\alpha L) - \alpha \cos(\beta L)]}$

These are clearly different, but are they both correct? Which one should be used?

Many thanks in advance for your help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips on how to use mathjax/latex to typeset math here. In particular add `\ ` in front of standard functions like `\sin(x)` to get proper formatting and fractions can be done as `\frac{ a } { b }`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments and apologies for my typos! It should all be correct now, but I don't suppose you could suggest a solution?!

Comment: Please give a scan of the page ( Google preview is limited).  Is it a pure buckling problem ?  Or is there a transverse load also ? The principle of superposition or combining between axial loading and lateral loading is *not* always valid.

Comment: I don't think the general solution that you proposed is the same for simply supported beam. Beam fixed with both ends are more complicated and in my opinion should have a different form. Plus, it is also symmetric. So it won't be one sinusoidal + one hyperbolic as you thought... just my 2 cents.

Comment: Your comment was addressed to OP, right?

Comment: @ AJG you can direct ask the book author also:   srao@miami.edu

Answer (score -1):

If the beam is fixed at both ends and subjected to axial loads, there would be *no deformation !*

Comment: Look at Euler's problem of [buckling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling) to see a counterexample...

Comment: In the classical Euler buckling axial translation  is permitted, leading to the buckling load $ \pi^2 EI/l^2$ or $ 4 \pi^2 EI/l^2$ depending on whether end rotation is allowed or suppressed. In the present case all degrees of freedom are arrested.

Comment: Exactly, although the ends of the beam are fixed into the supports, the tension is applied to the supports, i.e they are pulled apart